# How can i make an auto changing photo?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm a real beginner "coder", and I have work, to make an autochanging photo 
with a `textbox` (write xy sec, it will be the time between 2 image)

```
        string path = @"C:\Teszt\";            
        string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg");
        List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var item in Files)
        {
            fileList.Add(item);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Count; i++)
        {

            string year= "";
            year += DateTime.Now.Year;
            string month = "";
            month += DateTime.Now.Month;
            string day = "";
            day += DateTime.Now.Day;
            //update textbox
            Date.Content = year + "." + month + "." + day + ".";

            string filepath = fileList[i];
            var urii = new Uri(filepath);
            var bitmaap = new BitmapImage(urii);
            image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileList[i]));
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            if (i == fileList.Count)
                i = 0;
        }
    }
    private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(int.Parse(this.TextBox.Text)));
    }
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier if your variable names would be in English.

Comment: And what´s your question? Post where exactly you´ve got problems. Do you get any exceptions? Unexpected results?...

Comment: Yes, i know :D buy i think u can understand the most

Comment: you should make a timer and onTick event change the photo

Comment: What is `Date.Content`?

Comment: It doesn't work how i wanted:/ it doesn't change a photo, and it doesn't start instant at debugging just some seconds later.

Comment: Date is a textbox where i want to show the date of today.

Comment: @RomanoZumbé oh come on. variable names shouldn't matter ;)

Comment: @TimothyGroote They do in terms, that I always have to look back to their declarations and assignments to know what they are. If I would understand their names that would be done by the first examination ;-)

Comment: I get that, it was tongue-in-cheek. :p

Comment: Can someone help me in it? :/

Comment: @BenceHeszpuk Check my answer. that should help you along quite a bit

Comment: @BenceHeszpuk since it's quite a bit of code, i had to change a few things i noticed after posting the answer. i'm done now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- One thing you will want to do is split up your code in methods that have a clear, single responsibility. this makes your programs easier to understand
- The Date-in-a-textbox code has no business inside that loop
- You will need a way to do the waiting until the next picture in the
  background, so it will not block your UI thread, still allowing you
  to enter text in the textbox.
  The dispatcherTimer is a good way to go.
- you need to make sure the text in the textbox can be parsed to a number before doing anything

---

```
private List<string> kepek = new List<string>();
private int képnévIndex = 0;
private DispatcherTimer timer;


//this is my stand-in for your constructor. you didn't put it in the example, so i'm using "myClass"
public myClass()
{
    // you will still need InitializeComponent();
    InitializeComponent();

    LoadImages();
    setupTimer(10);
    displayCurrentDate();
}

private void setupTimer(int timeoutInSeconds)
{
    if(timer != null)
    {
        timer.Stop();
    }
    timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSeconds) };

    timer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
    {
         showNextPicture();
    };

    timer.Start();
}

private void LoadImages()
{
    string path = @"C:\Teszt\";            
    string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg");

    foreach (var item in Files)
    {
        kepek.Add(item);
    }
}

private void displayCurrentDate()
{
    string év = "";
    év += DateTime.Now.Year;
    string hónap = "";
    hónap += DateTime.Now.Month;
    string nap = "";
    nap += DateTime.Now.Day;              
    Date.Content = év + "." + hónap + "." + nap + ".";
}

private void showNextPicture()
{
    string képnév = kepek[képnévIndex];
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(képnév));

    képnévIndex++;

    if (képnévIndex == kepek.Count)
        képnévIndex = 0;

}

private void Szövegdoboz_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int parsedNumberOfSeconds;
    //if we entered something that can not be parsed to a number, exit.
    if(!int.tryParse(Szövegdoboz.Text, out parsedNumberOfSeconds))
        return;

    setupTimer(parsedNumberOfSeconds);
}
```

Comment: If it was helpful, opvote the answer. if it solved your problem, please mark it as your accepted answer.

Comment: But it stopped at timer.Start(); System.NullReferenceException

Comment: hmm, that's odd, can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: (or at least tell which element was null when we weren't expecting it to be?)

Comment: I'm using Hungarian VS So u can't understand it :/

Comment: try me ;) i might not speak hungarian, but i can read a stack trace.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException occurred
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Az objektumhivatkozás nincs beállítva semmilyen objektumpéldányra.
  Source=MajdnemKész
  StackTrace:
   at MajdnemKész.MainWindow..ctor() in c:\users\muszaki\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\MajdnemKész\MajdnemKész\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 32

Comment: Hmm, when you put the new code in the constructor, did you leave `InitializeComponent();` in place? (a WPF window or control does need that call to be in place)

Comment: I fixed it, but other problems with the setupTimer .  Type 'MainWindow' already defines a member called 'setupTimer' with the same parameter types

Comment: take another good look at the example, and the code you have in Visual studio now. my example does not have two definitions for `setupTimer`, so either you have messed up parentheses or brackets somewhere or you copied the `setupTimer` method twice.

Comment: The program is running, but not changing the img. I think need to check setupTimer, because when it shows the window, i need to wait 10 sec to see the img. and than i wait 10 sec but it doesn't do anything :/ and when i type something in the textbox, the time isn't changing

Comment: Kudos to you for holding your hand out to a beginner Mr. Hungarian Stack Trace Reader

Comment: Ha, i forgot to add `képnévIndex++`. hang on

Comment: it was missing from `showNextPicture`, but it's there now. also If you want to show the first image right from the start, just add a call to `showNextPicture` to the constructor ;)

Comment: And you're welcome for the help. we were all beginners one day, and a lot of people tend to forget that. thanks @AlexanderHiggins  #soreadytohelp

Comment: And idon't know why.. but when i want to change the timer that doesn't work too .. (it was working before)

Comment: Hi @BenceHeszpuk, i have no idea what you have changed in the meantime. take a good look at what you changed, and try to deduce what is not working and why. if you can't figure it out, post a new question please.